# Email indentation issue in yaml script in azure devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have used we script in yaml but am getting email with oneline content ( body) I need line breaks in email body.

```
  - template: /templates/python-v1
  - template: /templates/sendEmail
    parameters:
      to: ${{ parameters.to }}
      body: "Hi Team, This pull request has encountered errors: $(ERRORMESSAGE) Kindly address these issues and resubmit the pull request. Thank you. Sincerely, [DevOps Team]"
      from : ${{ parameters.from }}
      subject : ${{ parameters.subject }}
```

We have used we script in yaml but am getting email with oneline content ( body) I need line breaks in email body.

Comment: Then add the returns to your code.  The body is a string in your code and returns can be added.

Comment: Your YAML structure seems to be missing some components in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "|" after `body` to define the content.

Main yaml:

```
steps:
- template: templates/sendEmail.yml
  parameters:
    to: ${{ parameters.to }}
    body: |
      Hi Team, This pull request has encountered errors: 
      $(ERRORMESSAGE) 
      Kindly address these issues and resubmit the pull request. 
      Thank you. 
      Sincerely, 
      [DevOps Team]
    from : ${{ parameters.from }}
    subject : ${{ parameters.subject }}
```

Template yaml:

```
parameters:
- name: to  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  default: ''
- name: from
  default: ''
- name: subject
  default: ''
- name: body
  default: ''

steps:
- task: SendEmail@1
  inputs:
    To: ${{ parameters.to }}
    From: ${{ parameters.from }}
    Subject: ${{ parameters.subject }}
    Body: ${{ parameters.body }}
    BodyAsHtml: false
    AddAttachment: false
    SmtpServer: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
    SmtpUsername: '$(useremail)'
    SmtpPassword: '$(pwd)'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: HI, I need line breaks in mail body  like HI team is in first line and then " the pull request has en......" in 2 nd line. Could you please help me

Comment: You can simply move the string " the pull request has en......" into 2nd line in the body content as other strings in the sample above. With "|" after body, you can `prepare` the format which you want to output.

Comment: @devendraPadhi, in the sample shared above, if i prepare the body format, it can be correctly sent by task `SendEmail@1`. If you are using other command/task to send the email, please add the details in the ticket statement, thanks.